# Change IPython stream encoding

Tags: python, python-3.x, ipython, python-unicode

I'm using an Anaconda install of Python 3.6.3 and IPython 6.1.0 on Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7.5 .  I have text files containing Unicode characters that I'm trying to work with, but I get the following error when trying to print the contents of these files:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\U0001f644' in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I believe this is due to IPython defaulting to an ASCII encoding:

```
In [1]: from IPython.utils.encoding import get_stream_enc; import sys

In [2]: get_stream_enc(sys.stdout)
Out[2]: 'ANSI_X3.4-1968'
```

I can't find anything in the IPython documentation explaining how to change this to UTF-8.  Is it possible?

Comment: I'd expect that iPython is getting the encoding from the environment (`$LANG` etc).  The ideal solution is to change the environment setting, or set the PYTHONIOENCODING environment variable (I discuss a similar situation is [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54599110/5320906).

Comment: @snakecharmerb Thanks! This is correct, and fixed my issue. Do you want to post this as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iPython takes its output encoding from the environment.  To use a unicode-aware encoding, either change your user's *locale* settings or set the [PYTHONIOENCODING](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONIOENCODING) environment variable when calling iPython:

```
PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8 ipython
```